# How to force LTR direction in wordpress with rtl language seleted

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and iam using rtl enabled theme

So when i choose the main language of wordpress as "arabic"

The theme changes automatic to rtl

Is there any way to force it not to change direction even with Arabic language selected in wordpress dashboard??

Answer (score -1):

RTL is done through CSS. When you use a theme it has styles such as `float:right` on certain elements so that that element goes to the right site. Or other CSS styles such as `text-align: right`. It depends on what element of the theme such as navigation, text, widgets, icons. They all will have and need different styles.

Therefore your question is impossible to answer. 
Especially if you did not provide any code examples, screenshots or links.